# How can I delete the uploaded video on facebook?

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I've used [Facebook SDK](http://csharpsdk.org/) for uploading the video on Facebook, everything works fine but I couldn't find any way to delete the video that is uploaded?

**I can delete the Video post by API (USERID_VideoID), but the video still in Facebook and can access by direct url. So is it any way tomake the video private by API?**

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know delete video is not supported via the API.Normally interaction with facebook pro-grammatically  is through HTTP requests.What you can try doing is send an HTTP DELETE call to the video object